# Django REST api

Tags: python, django, api, rest

I'm using Django's rest framework and currently set up I have

a url /api/course/

which shows a list of courses that are already in the database. Courses have a Lecture foreign key and I want to make it so that you can access each course's lectures.

Currently I've set it up so that /api/lectures takes you to all the lectures.

```
router.register(r'course', views.CourseViewSet)
router.register(r'lecture', views.LectureViewSet)
```

However, I'm not sure how to set it up so that when you look at course Math, you only get Math lectures..

Thanks!

Edit: My models:

```
class Lecture(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True, null=True)
    recordings = models.ForeignKey(Recording, null=True)
    keywords = models.ForeignKey(Keyword, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Course(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    lecturer = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    lectures = models.ForeignKey(Lecture, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: can you show your models?

Comment: @GeoJacob Sure, I've added them now

Comment: According to your models, there will be only one lecture for one course. If you want multiple lectures then you need to change the relation as manytomany. Or you have to give course as foreign key field in lecture model, if one lecture will take only on course.

Comment: As well as changing the foreign key to a many to many, another option is to move the foreign key from the `Course` model to the `Lecture` model. It depends whether you want each lecture to belong to one course (then put the foreign key on `Lecture`, or whether a lecture can belong to multiple courses (then use a many-to-many).

Comment: @Alasdair A course has a number of lectures so I should have course = models.ForeignKey(Course) as an attr of Lecture?

Comment: That's right, as long as each lecture belongs to *only one* course. If a lecture can belong to more than one course (e.g. a lecture is part of the maths course and physics course), then you need a many to many.

Answer (score 0):

So here is the answer; You can use detail route for such situations;
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/ go through DRF routing documentation;

```
class CourseViewSet(ModelViewSet):

    @detail_route(methods=['get'])
    def lectures(self, request, pk=None):
        # code to get all lectures of your current course
        # pk will be course id(ex: id of Maths course)
        data = {} # serialize the data
        return Response(data)
```

so your url will be like;

```
/courses/id/lectures
```

Comment: I'm not sure I quite follow what is happening here exactly. Could you explain with a more complete example? Apologies, I am still new at this.